# Outlook add-in error: The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

i am trying to create my own add-in for Outlook. My point is to extract some data from mails and then move these mails to Archive folder. When i open unread mails it works as i expect, but i got an error when i open unread mails in the moment when i am trying to move mail to Archive folder. I got an instance of mail from inspector. Here is some code.

```
 Outlook.MailItem mail = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;

 var email = mail.UserProperties.Session.CurrentUser.Address;
 Outlook.NameSpace ouNs = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
 Outlook.MAPIFolder baseFolder = ouNs.Folders[email];
 var archiveFolder = findFolderRecursive(baseFolder, archiveFolderName);

 mail.Move(archiveFolder);
```

Comment: When exactly do you get the error? Move the message when the inspector is being closed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I got the error here: mail.Move(archiveFolder). Also tried to close inspector and release it first:                       inspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olSave);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inspector);
But it didnt help, the same problem with mails, that were unread before i opened.

Answer (score 0):

Messages returned from the inspector disallow some methods. Try to track the Inspector.Close event, store the message entry id in a variable, and enable a timer (use Timer class from the Forms namespace - it runs on the same thread). When the timer fires, disable it, open the item by its entry id using Namespace.GetItemFromID, then move it.